# Moving BitmapFont with camera LibGDX

Tags: javascript, java, android, camera, libgdx

Hi I am beginner in LibGDX.
I have a moving camera and I want to display score while is camera moving.
I have done yet this but the Text(Score) shake when camera move.
I have no idea how to fix this.
Here is my code.

```
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    sb.begin();
    String s = Integer.toString(SCORE);
    String h = Integer.toString(highscore);

    sb.draw(bg,cam.position.x - (cam.viewportWidth /2),0);


    sb.draw(groud,groundpos1.x,groundpos1.y);
    sb.draw(groud,groundpos2.x,groundpos2.y);


    font.draw(sb,s,cam.position.x-font.getSpaceWidth(),cam.position.y+(cam.viewportHeight /2)-39);
    high.draw(sb,h,cam.position.x- (cam.viewportWidth /2),cam.position.y+(cam.viewportHeight /2)-39);
    sb.end();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it shakes is because text positions are rounded off to integer positions by default. You could set `font.setUseIntegerPositions(false)` on each of your text objects to avoid this.

However, it's not practical to try to move your GUI around with your game world's camera. Create a separate camera for your GUI.

```
public void render(SpriteBatch sb) {
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(gameCam.combined);
    sb.begin();

    sb.draw(bg,gameCam.position.x - (gameCam.viewportWidth /2),0);

    sb.draw(groud,groundpos1.x,groundpos1.y);
    sb.draw(groud,groundpos2.x,groundpos2.y);


    sb.setProjectionMatrix(guiCam.combined);
    String s = Integer.toString(SCORE);
    String h = Integer.toString(highscore);
    font.draw(sb, s, font.getSpaceWidth(), guiCam.viewportHeight / 2 - 39);
    high.draw(sb, h, guiCam.viewportWidth /2, guiCam.viewportHeight / 2 - 39);
    sb.end();
}
```